# Recommendation for math software?

Tags: calculus, math-software, symbolic-computation

I’m looking for program or an online web page that would do following:

Take a function of multiple variables,  allow me to set one of the variables to a fixed value then simplify resulting function.

Is able to find partial derivatives of a function

Is able to find integral over a region.  Preferably would give a function, otherwise would numerically integrate.

I think maple does this but I’m wondering if there is any freeware ?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/ can do a lot ...

Comment: I tried the wolframalpha and it seems to do what I want,  at least with simple functions.  I will try some more complicated stuff but so far so good.

Comment: [symbolab.com](https://www.symbolab.com/) can be a little unwieldy sometimes, but it's worked well for me. I'm not sure if it does all of those things, but it's a start.